# How to store a non changeable variable in do-while?

Tags: java

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    char input1;
        String inputInfo = new String();
        String line = new String();
        String caseS = new String();
        boolean found;

    public static void main(string [] args){
        switch (input1)
                    {
                        case 'A':   //Add Order
                            System.out.print("Please enter an order information to add:\n");
                            inputInfo = stdin.readLine().trim();
                            caseS = inputInfo; // assigning value of string to case S

                            Order defaultOrder = OrderParser.parseStringToAnOrder(inputInfo);

                            orderList.add(defaultOrder);
                        case 'S':   //Search for an Order
                            System.out.print("Please enter a product name to search:\n");
                            inputInfo = stdin.readLine().trim();

                            Scanner scan = new Scanner(caseS);
                            caseS.useDelimiter("/");

                            String [] caseSArray = new String[6];

                            while(scan.hasNext()){

                                for(int i = 0; i < caseSArray.length; i++){

                                    caseSArray[i] = scan.next();
                                }
                            }
    }
}
```

I would like to save the previous inputs of the user under case 'A'(non changeable variables) so that I could compare the inputs of Strings of different users together.
How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like save a previous input(one input) and compare it with those inputs in `main`, you can make static variable called lastInput and store it there.

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    char input1;
        String inputInfo = new String();
        String line = new String();
        String caseS = new String();
        boolean found;

    public static Order lastOrder;  // -> *** CODE CHANGED HERE ***

    public static void main(string [] args){
        switch (input1)
                {
                    case 'A':   //Add Order
                        System.out.print("Please enter an order information to add:\n");
                        inputInfo = stdin.readLine().trim();
                        caseS = inputInfo; // assigning value of string to case S

                        Order defaultOrder = OrderParser.parseStringToAnOrder(inputInfo);
                        lastOrder = defaultOrder; // -> *** CODE CHANGED HERE ***
                        orderList.add(defaultOrder);
                    case 'S':   //Search for an Order
                        System.out.print("Please enter a product name to search:\n");
                        inputInfo = stdin.readLine().trim();

                        Scanner scan = new Scanner(caseS);
                        caseS.useDelimiter("/");

                        String [] caseSArray = new String[6];

                        while(scan.hasNext()){

                            for(int i = 0; i < caseSArray.length; i++){

                                caseSArray[i] = scan.next();
                            }
                        }
}
```

}